# Android changing text on buttons programatically

Tags: android, button, android-linearlayout, dynamically-generated

I am making a grid of buttons 4 wide, 9 tall, all of the buttons are invisible and no text on them, I then programatically add text to them and make them visible (basically I am using the invisible buttons because any of the 36 buttons can become visible due to the code for making them visible (it's based on an XML document I am parsing) I am using LinearLayout to do this, so I have a Vertical LinearLayout, wrapped in 9 Horizontal LinearLayouts with 4 buttons in each, all of them have wrap_content height and width and weight 1 (not sure if this could be causing the problem as I am not entirely sure how these parameters work yet).

My problem is that once I get to the adding text, the text can be different lengths, and so my buttons end up odd shapes with some being wider or something taller than others, is there any way to do this in a way that means that they will all end up similar sizes? or will my invisible buttons mess things up? Or is there a better way to do what I am doing?

I worry about using fixed size buttons as I figure if the text is too long it will cause issues that way instead.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/soulOneLL"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="soulOne"
            android:text="@string/SoulOne"
            android:id="@+id/btnSoul1" />

    </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="soulOneRowColumn"
        android:id="@+id/btnSoulOnRow8Column0" />

        <Button
   android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="soulOneRowColumn"
            android:id="@+id/btnSoulOneRow8Column1" />

        <Button
   android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="soulOneRowColumn"
            android:id="@+id/btnSoulOneRow8Column2" />

        <Button
   android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="soulOneRowColumn"
            android:id="@+id/btnSoulOneRow8Column3" />
        </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <Button
   android:visibility="invisible"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="soulOneRowColumn"
                android:id="@+id/btnSoulOneRow7Column0" />

            <Button
   android:visibility="invisible"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="soulOneRowColumn"
                android:id="@+id/btnSoulOneRow7Column1" />

            <Button
   android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="soulOneRowColumn"
            android:id="@+id/btnSoulOneRow7Column2" />
            <Button
   android:visibility="invisible"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="soulOneRowColumn"
                android:id="@+id/btnSoulOneRow7Column3" />

    </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <Button
   android:visibility="invisible"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:onClick="soulOneRowColumn"
                    android:id="@+id/btnSoulOneRow6Column0" />

                <Button
   android:visibility="invisible"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:onClick="soulOneRowColumn"
                    android:id="@+id/btnSoulOneRow6Column1" />

                <Button
   android:visibility="invisible"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:onClick="soulOneRowColumn"
                    android:id="@+id/btnSoulOneRow6Column2" />
                <Button
   android:visibility="invisible"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:onClick="soulOneRowColumn"
                    android:id="@+id/btnSoulOneRow6Column3" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <Button
   android:visibility="invisible"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:onClick="soulOneRowColumn"
                    android:id="@+id/btnSoulOneRow5Column0" />

                <Button
   android:visibility="invisible"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:onClick="soulOneRowColumn"
                    android:id="@+id/btnSoulOneRow5Column1" />

                <Button
   android:visibility="invisible"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:onClick="soulOneRowColumn"
                    android:id="@+id/btnSoulOneRow5Column2" />
                <Button
   android:visibility="invisible"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:onClick="soulOneRowColumn"
                    android:id="@+id/btnSoulOneRow5Column3" />


            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <Button
   android:visibility="invisible"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:onClick="soulOneRowColumn"
                    android:id="@+id/btnSoulOneRow4Column0" />

                <Button
   android:visibility="invisible"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:onClick="soulOneRowColumn"
                    android:id="@+id/btnSoulOneRow4Column1" />

                <Button
   android:visibility="invisible"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:onClick="soulOneRowColumn"
                    android:id="@+id/btnSoulOneRow4Column2" />
                <Button
   android:visibility="invisible"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:onClick="soulOneRowColumn"
                    android:id="@+id/btnSoulOneRow4Column3" />

            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <Button
   android:visibility="invisible"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:onClick="soulOneRowColumn"
                    android:id="@+id/btnSoulOneRow3Column0" />

                <Button
   android:visibility="invisible"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:onClick="soulOneRowColumn"
                    android:id="@+id/btnSoulOneRow3Column1" />

                <Button
   android:visibility="invisible"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:onClick="soulOneRowColumn"
                    android:id="@+id/btnSoulOneRow3Column2" />
                <Button
   android:visibility="invisible"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:onClick="soulOneRowColumn"
                    android:id="@+id/btnSoulOneRow3Column3" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <Button
   android:visibility="invisible"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:onClick="soulOneRowColumn"
                    android:id="@+id/btnSoulOneRow2Column0" />

                <Button
   android:visibility="invisible"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:onClick="soulOneRowColumn"
                    android:id="@+id/btnSoulOneRow2Column1" />

                <Button
   android:visibility="invisible"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:onClick="soulOneRowColumn"
                    android:id="@+id/btnSoulOneRow2Column2" />
                <Button
   android:visibility="invisible"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:onClick="soulOneRowColumn"
                    android:id="@+id/btnSoulOneRow2Column3" />

            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <Button
   android:visibility="invisible"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:onClick="soulOneRowColumn"
                    android:id="@+id/btnSoulOneRow1Column0" />

                <Button
   android:visibility="invisible"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:onClick="soulOneRowColumn"
                    android:id="@+id/btnSoulOneRow1Column1" />

                <Button
   android:visibility="invisible"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:onClick="soulOneRowColumn"
                    android:id="@+id/btnSoulOneRow1Column2" />
                <Button
   android:visibility="invisible"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:onClick="soulOneRowColumn"
                    android:id="@+id/btnSoulOneRow1Column3" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <Button
   android:visibility="invisible"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:onClick="soulOneRowColumn"
                    android:id="@+id/btnSoulOneRow0Column0" />

                <Button
   android:visibility="invisible"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:onClick="soulOneRowColumn"
                    android:id="@+id/btnSoulOneRow0Column1" />

                <Button
   android:visibility="invisible"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:onClick="soulOneRowColumn"
                    android:id="@+id/btnSoulOneRow0Column2" />
                <Button
   android:visibility="invisible"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:onClick="soulOneRowColumn"
                    android:id="@+id/btnSoulOneRow0Column3" />

            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Can you post your layout files?

Comment: have edited with the layout file that is being used

Comment: I think you want your horizontal layouts to fill the width. Your buttons also should fill width. You set the layout_weight to 1, so that means they should evenly take up 1/3 each.

Comment: well, i did this.. it has made the buttons more or less the same.. but text inside them looks weird as it cuts off some of them, and some have a single letter on a new line

Comment: Well, if you're looking for something to dynamically choose a font so that all your texts fit, I don't think that's going to happen. If you're using a default font size, then it's going to have to cut off the text if there isn't enough space, or attempt to word wrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On each button, you can give an `android:maxLength` attribute and `android:maxLines` attribute. These will constrain the text to a certain size and length, guaranteeing they will all be the same size.

Comment: only problem is i don't know how long the text might be, seems currently that it is all being messed up by one text being much longer than other on same line

Comment: If you want to ensure they are all the same size, there are some that are going to be too long than others. I guess I'm not understanding what kind of solution you want if this doesn't work? Are you saying that you want all buttons to be the same size as the largest button in the set?

Comment: not entirely sure what I want  to be honest, 1) I want all the available text to be visible on all buttons, 2) I want it not to cut text off at random points because of the way that it has allocated size of buttons, so I guess that might be a solution if that is possible. Main problem seems to be to do with different lengths and words, like one example a 9 character word gets the 9th character on a new line on its own, while next to it on same row a 9 character but two words (so I suppose 10 with the blank space) works fine because it just seems to go to new line with the same instead

Comment: To be honest I don't think there is an easy and clean way to do this. My initial thought is that you will have to iterate over every button and determine the amount of text in each button, then use that parameter to set the size of every button on a second pass, which sounds really intensive and draining on resources.

Comment: Accepted your answer as it lead me to my own solution and yours was the only actual answer on here to do so with, thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Decided based on the answers provided that nothing could be done that would work the way I wanted, so I changed it so that instead of showing the text on the buttons, I made a dialog pop up with some information instead which works for what I wanted anyway.